# Detecting All Occurrences of Subimage Within Image

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

Recently, I've been developing a small side project that needs the ability to find the X & Y coordinates of a subimage within another image. The images might be in different resolutions, but overall the image resolutions will be similar and the colors should be the same. I have looked into OpenCV, but it seems that OpenCV only returns a single match. I need to find all occurrences/instances of the subimage inside of the super-image. I already have all of the subimages to search for, so I am only in need of a way to find the coordinates of the subimages within the super-image.

Here's an example of what I mean:

If we have `red_circle.png`:

[image: Red Circle Subimage]

and `shapes.png`:

[image: Shapes Super-Image]

I need to get the X & Y coordinates for **all** of the red circles (`red_circle.png`; subimage) within the picture of various shapes (`shapes.png`; super-image).

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
/* code to read in red_cirlce.png and shapes.png as BufferedImages */
ArrayList<Point> instancesOfRedCircle = new ArrayList<>();
findAllSubimageInstances( shapesObj, // Super-Image
                          redCircleObj, // Subimage
                          instancesOfRedCircle // ArrayList to put points in
                        );
```

Does anybody know of a way to do this (eg, a library, a function, etcetera)?

Comment: opencv matchTemplate function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could not sleep that nigth..

[image]

I have written the code from the tuorial in java and build a little gui around it.

```
package opencv.test;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDMatch;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.features2d.DMatch;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class MatchDetection {

    public static BufferedImage detectMatches(File file, File file2) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat img_1 = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat img_2 = Highgui.imread(file2.getAbsolutePath(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if (img_1.empty() || img_2.empty()) {
            System.out.println(" --(!) Error reading images ");
            return null;
        }

        // -- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
        //I am not sure where to use it
        int minHessian = 400;

        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);

        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
        detector.detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

        // -- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
        DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor
                .create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);

        Mat descriptors_1 = new Mat();
        Mat descriptors_2 = new Mat();

        extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
        extractor.compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

        // -- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher
                .create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
        matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);
        DMatch[] matchesArr = matches.toArray();

        double max_dist = 0;
        double min_dist = 100;

        // -- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
        for (int i = 0; i < matchesArr.length; i++) {
            double dist = matchesArr[i].distance;
            if (dist < min_dist)
                min_dist = dist;
            if (dist > max_dist)
                max_dist = dist;
        }

        System.out.printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
        System.out.printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

        // -- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than
        // 2*min_dist,
        // -- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is
        // very
        // -- small)
        // -- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
        MatOfDMatch good_matches = new MatOfDMatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < matchesArr.length; i++) {
            if (matchesArr[i].distance <= Math.max(2 * min_dist, 0.02)) {
                good_matches.push_back(matches.row(i));
            }
        }

        // -- Draw only "good" matches
        Mat img_matches = new Mat();
        Features2d.drawMatches(img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2,
                good_matches, img_matches);//, Scalar.all(-1), Scalar.all(-1),
                //null, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

        // ----Here i had to Patch around a little----
        MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();

        Highgui.imencode(".jpg", img_matches, matOfByte);

        byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
        BufferedImage bufImage = null;
        try {

            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
            bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) good_matches.rows(); i++) {
            System.out.printf(
                    "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n",
                    i, good_matches.toArray()[i].queryIdx,
                    good_matches.toArray()[i].trainIdx);
        }

        return bufImage;

    }
}
```

and the GUI

```
package opencv.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class OpenCVMyGui {

    private JFrame frame;
    ImageResultPanel panel_bot;
    ImageChoosePanel panel_left;
    ImageChoosePanel panel_right;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OpenCVMyGui window = new OpenCVMyGui();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public OpenCVMyGui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        panel_left = new ImageChoosePanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_panel_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel_2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panel_2.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_left, gbc_panel_2);

        panel_right = new ImageChoosePanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_panel_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel_1.gridx = 1;
        gbc_panel_1.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_right, gbc_panel_1);

        panel_bot = new ImageResultPanel(this);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_bot, gbc_panel);
    }

    private class ImageChoosePanel extends JPanel {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2207576827793103205L;
        public BufferedImage image;
        public File file;

        public ImageChoosePanel() {
            setFocusable(true);
            addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images",
                            "jpg", "png")); // maybe more? dont know what OpenCV
                                            // likes
                    chooser.showOpenDialog(ImageChoosePanel.this);
                    ImageChoosePanel icp = ((ImageChoosePanel) e.getSource());
                    icp.file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(icp.file);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics arg0) {

            if (image != null) {
                arg0.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            } else{ 
                arg0.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    private class ImageResultPanel extends JPanel {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8948107638933808175L;
        public BufferedImage image;
        OpenCVMyGui gui;

        public ImageResultPanel(OpenCVMyGui gui) {
            this.gui = gui;
            setFocusable(true);
            addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        OpenCVMyGui gui = ((ImageResultPanel) arg0.getSource()).gui;
                        image = MatchDetection.detectMatches(
                                gui.panel_right.file, gui.panel_left.file);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics arg0) {
            if (image != null) {
                arg0.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }else{
                arg0.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You should definity play around with the algorithms... but the result atm should help you with your goals.

I might read over it again. Tomorrow.

Comment: My god, you definitely deserve more than one upvote for this answer. This answer is extremely complete and extremely helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher

Its C++ code but you can guess how it works und OpenCV has a java Api which is pretty close to the C++ Api.

I hope that helps you.

If you think this shoots far over the target you could just try to iterate over the pixelx. But it would be complicated with the different sizes.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize OpenCV could do that. I'll give that a try when I have some free time.